# ActiveRecord on local console not working, but works with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, rails-console

I'm rather baffled right now.

I have a database full of airport data.  I'm trying to call certain attributes from different records in my console, but it isn't working.  Oddly enough it works fine in my heroku console. For example:

If I put:  x = Airport.where(code: "JFK").  When I type "x" in my console I get the entire record for JFK.  But, when I type x.runway_length I get a method error.

The odd thing is when I do the same process in my Heroku console, I'll get the runway length (or any other attribute I attach to "x").

What's going on?  Am I missing something.

Thanks!

x = Airport.where(code: "LAX")

```
Airport Load (2.9ms)  SELECT "airports".* FROM "airports" WHERE "airports"."code" = 'LAX'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Airport id: 3533, code: "LAX", lat: 33.9456, lon: -118.391, name: "Los Angeles International Airport", city: "Los Angeles", state: "California", country: "United States", woeid: 12520706, tz: "America/Los_Angeles", phone: "", email: "", url: "", runway_length: 12091, elev: 126, icao: "KLAX", direct_flights: 200, carriers: 99, created_at: "2015-08-06 19:10:03", updated_at: "2015-08-17 03:05:53", current_high_temp: 84, current_low_temp: 70>]>
```

Now, when I try: x.current_high_temp

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `current_high_temp' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Airport:0x007fd89ed33b18>
```

Comment: Could you post exact commands and responses? Both local and Heroku.

Comment: try restarting your local console or run `reload!`

Comment: With `x = Airport.where(code: "JFK")` you are getting an __array__ of airports, where the attribute `code` is "JFK". Try `x = Airport.where(code: "JFK").first` and then `x.runway_length`.

Comment: @Zepplock I added the code.

Comment: Please try what ``zhurora`` proposed

Comment: @zhurora, That worked.  Odd, I don't have to do that on Heroku!   Is there a different command I can do so i don't have to do "first"?

Comment: @zhurora seems right, try it

Comment: @RossRobertMcKee in heroku you are using postgres db propably where as in local maybe you are using sqlite which is the default.

Comment: In X you don't have an object, you have a collection of objects, so you have to extract each one and call the method current_high_temp x.each { |airport| airport.current_high_temp}

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou  Thank you.  Will that affect my code when I push to heroku later?

Comment: @RossRobertMcKee some things are different,like the ordering of items in sqlite is item 1,item2,item3, on postgres items are not ordered by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Where' returns an array, and you are calling an instance method on it.

Try

```
x = Airport.where(code: "LAX").first
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the method you are using.

`Model#where` does not return an object (as expected from active record) for you to work with, instead you should use `Model#find_by(attribute: expression)`

In your case use:

```
x = Airport.find_by(code: "LAX")
```

Comment: But you should only use `find_by` when you are sure, that the `code` attribute is unique! Otherwise you might get different Airport objects depending on how your records are sorted or `find_by` is implemented in Rails. But I guess, that in your case it should be OK.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I just asumed that airport codes were unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
where(opts = :chain, *rest) public
```

Returns a new relation, which is the result of filtering the current relation according to the conditions in the arguments.

i.e.

```
x = Airport.where(code: "LAX")

Airport Load (2.9ms)  SELECT "airports".* FROM "airports" WHERE "airports"."code" = 'LAX'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Airport id: 3533, code: "LAX", lat: 33.9456, lon: -118.391, name: "Los Angeles International Airport", city: "Los Angeles", state: "California", country: "United States", woeid: 12520706, tz: "America/Los_Angeles", phone: "", email: "", url: "", runway_length: 12091, elev: 126, icao: "KLAX", direct_flights: 200, carriers: 99, created_at: "2015-08-06 19:10:03", updated_at: "2015-08-17 03:05:53", current_high_temp: 84, current_low_temp: 70>]>
```

you notice that the Object type is `ActiveRecord::Relation` instead of `Airport` and the `Airport` object is wrapped with array literals `[]` however, the collection type is not array. So,
Either you want to use

```
x = Airport.where(code: "LAX").first
or 
x = Airport.where(code: "LAX")[0] # not recommended
```

If 'code' is a unique key the you might use

```
# this gives the first airport with code = 'LAX'
x = Airport.find_by_code("LAX")
```

or if you want to see the `current_high_temp` of all airports then you might want to do this

```
x = Airport.where(code: "LAX").pluck('current_high_temp')
```

> pluck(*column_names) public Use pluck as a shortcut to select one or
>   more attributes without loading a bunch of records just to grab the
>   attributes you want.
>
> `Person.pluck(:name)`
>   instead of
>   `Person.all.map(&:name)`